# How to embed JQuery into custom server control

Tags: .net, jquery, custom-server-controls

I am writing a server control that is a search box with suggestions (when the user starts typing, matching words will appear for them to select).  I am using jquery and C#.

The control works fine when I include the jquery Lib on the page that I am testing on.  However, it will not work when I attempt to embed the lib in the DLL.

I have tried completely embedding it and registering the script:

```
ClientScriptManager manager = this.Page.ClientScript;
manager.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(Search), jqueryResource); //jqueryResource= SearchControl.javascript.jquery.js
```

and I am also tried just adding a tag in the header of the page that includes the jquery:

```
string javascriptUrl = manager.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Search), jqueryResource); 
LiteralControl jquery = new LiteralControl(string.Format(javascriptInclude, jqueryUrl));
Page.Header.Controls.Add(jquery);
```

Both ways cause javascript errors (Object Expected) when trying to get information from controls

```
var params = $("#searchBox").val(); //called on keyup when typing in textbox
```

Has someone done this before?  Is it possible?  Can someone shed some light on this?

PS: Assemblies are already registered in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: Just re-read your question and realised I've just repeated what you've done. However this is my implementation which works as expected:

You need to use `RegisterClientScriptResource`. Just call the following snippet (taken from my ScriptRegisterHelper static class) in the PreRender event of the control:

```
/// <summary>
/// Registers the jQuery client script to the page.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cs">The ClientScriptManager to assign the script to.</param>
internal static void RegisterJQuery(ClientScriptManager cs)
{
    cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(ScriptRegisterHelper), 
        "MyProject.Resources.jquery.js");
}
```

And for completion, here's the implentation:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {

       // Register the JavaScript libraries
       ClientScriptManager cs = this.Page.ClientScript;
       ScriptRegisterHelper.RegisterJQuery(cs);

    }
}
```

And the AssemblyInfo file:

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("MyProject.Resources.jquery.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did initially and it still didnt work. Then something clicked while I continued to ponder it.  I looked at the script file build action and Guess What?  That's right, I forgot to set this one to be an embedded resource (You think it would do this when you register the assemblies).  Anyway, it works like a charm now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I knew I should have mentioned that as well! Doh.

Comment: Thanks for this reminder on setting the resource to be Embedded. This was driving me crazy.